# Calculate probability of outcome of a medical procedure

Tags: regression, probability, binary-data, logistic-curve

I have data on medical procedures completed at hospitals in major U.S hospitals. Each medical procedure is assigned a code, for example: Kidney Transplant is X6571.

[image: DATA]

I define the success criteria and create a 'good' and 'bad' binary outcome whether. I have other variables such as wait time before surgery, other medical complication, patient age, frequency of surgeries that I control for.

For each medical procedure surgery code, I'd like to obtain a probability of success score. What models / techniques would be appropriate for this problem? I am open to suggestions beyond regression models.

Comment: Why do you ask `beyond regression models`? Is a logistic regression model not good enough?

Comment: It's an option, however, I want to explore other methods as well and compare accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

This sound like a typical classification problem. So, beyond logistic regression, which is actually a probability modelling technique under the assumption of normally distributed classes, there is a great choice of machine learning methods: (k) nearest neighbour(s) classifier, neural networks (multi-layer perceptrons), support vector machines, random forests, and many more. There is a link on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Classification_algorithms), and this [sister site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41844311/list-of-all-classification-algorithms) offers a list of algorithms available in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Since each record of a surgery is either "good" or "bad", it can be considered as a Bernoulli distribution with the probability of $p$ for "good" and $1-p$ for "bad". Based on the surgery records for each surgery code type, you may calculate a confidence interval (CI) of $p$ corresponding to a specified confidence level(CL, e.g. CL=95%) to indicate the rate of the surgery successfulness.